# windows 8 local html file as background

Tags: html, windows, wallpaper

As far as i can tell, windows officially removed option to set web page and/or local html as desktop wallpaper, when win vista was released..
Personally i, as web developer, totally loved this feature.
And i was sad, when i found out that my windows 8.1 (64bit) can't do this anymore.

I understand, that MS did this for security reasons.. but still, i wanted to know, is there some way to make a LOCAL html file as a wallaper in windows 8.1, or can i make some sort of live wallpaper with web languages..?

If someone knows anything, that could be close, to what i want to achieve, please let me know..

Comment: Good question but I think this should be migrated to SuperUser